# Is variadic macro expansion possible in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, c-preprocessor

In C99 we have variadic macro expansion via the `#define XXX(...) __VA_ARGS__` syntax.

This doesn't seem to work in GLSL. 
Is there a similar mechanism with different syntax? Is this implementation specific?

Comment: You can always run the preprocessor separately, so it can be used to preprocess arbitrary files (like for example GLSL source files).

Comment: Or use prerpocessor as a library (there are quite a few implementations) and apply it to glsl "strings" in runtime. In fact, any decent template processing language will do (as well as good old regex for simple cases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GLSL specification [borrows most of its preprocessor behavior from C++](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#preprocessor). Specifically, [C++98](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#references). As such, it does not have variadic macros. Nor does it have anything like them.